# disable previous date in custom android datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to disable previous date in rey5137's datepicker dialog, this is the code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog.Builder builder = null;

        builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(R.style.Material_App_Dialog_DatePicker){
            @Override
            public void onPositiveActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog)fragment.getDialog();
                String date = dialog.getFormattedDate(SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance());
                pilih_tgl.setText(date);
                super.onPositiveActionClicked(fragment);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNegativeActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                super.onNegativeActionClicked(fragment);
            }
        };

        builder.positiveAction("OK")
                .negativeAction("CANCEL");

        DialogFragment fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance(builder);

        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
    }
```

where should I put setMinDate in my code?
any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dateRange to your builder. you can set maxDate as you wish.

```
Dialog.Builder builder = null;
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              int year =  c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+200;
                c.set(year,c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DATE));
                builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(R.style.Material_App_Dialog_DatePicker) {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositiveActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                        DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog) fragment.getDialog();
                        String date = dialog.getFormattedDate(SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance());
                        //pilih_tgl.setText(date);
                        super.onPositiveActionClicked(fragment);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNegativeActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                        super.onNegativeActionClicked(fragment);
                    }
                }.dateRange(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000, c.getTimeInMillis());
                builder.positiveAction("OK")
                        .negativeAction("CANCEL");
                DialogFragment fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance(builder);

                fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks...it did the trick...just have to change getSupportFragmentManager() to getFragmentManager()...

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

which sets today's date as minimum date and all the past dates are disabled.

`datePicker` is an object of `DatePicker` if you are using an object of `DatePickerDialog` you can do

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Comment: I just want modify rey5137's datepicker for my need, if I use the code listed above that means I will use another datepicker lib entirely...but thanks for the answer...

Comment: where should I put setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000) in my code because if I put it behind dialog, it gives me an error...

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code as below :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Dialog.Builder builder = null;

    builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(R.style.Material_App_Dialog_DatePicker){
        @Override
        public void onPositiveActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
            DatePickerDialog dialog = (DatePickerDialog)fragment.getDialog();
            dialog = dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            String date = dialog.getFormattedDate(SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance());
            pilih_tgl.setText(date);
            super.onPositiveActionClicked(fragment);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNegativeActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
            super.onNegativeActionClicked(fragment);
        }
    };

    builder.positiveAction("OK")
            .negativeAction("CANCEL");

    DialogFragment fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance(builder);

    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still I dont use getDatePicker... @Dhina's code did the work